# Returning an unevaluated expression with values substituted in

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching

Let's say I have a function

```
formula[x_List] := (x[[1]] - x[[2]]) + (x[[3]] - x[[4]]);
```

and I want to pass it a variable and get back the unevaluated formula with these inputs in place, so for example with input {1,2,3,4} I would get back

```
Out[]= (1-2)+(3-4)
```

I do not want it to return strings; if I copy the output and paste it somewhere, I want it to be executable. I also don't want it to do any math on the function; if `x[[1]]==x[[2]]`, it should not collapse `x[[1]]-x[[2]]` to 0. All I want is pattern substitution.

I figure the answer involves `Hold[]`, but I have not been able to get the results I want.

Comment: Both the Mr. Wizard and Mike Honeychurch have solutions that come very close to what I want. In fact, at first I thought they both had it. I notice however that there is a case in which both methods fail. Both simplify out certain simple identities. For example, if formula[{a_, b_, c_, d_}] := HoldForm[a*b*c*d], then both versions drop some 1s given as input (oddly, not all). formula[{1,1,1,1}] works as desired but formula[1,2,1,31] does not.

Comment: Michael, I have addressed this problem in my answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
formula[{a_, b_, c_, d_}] := Defer[(a - b) + (c - d)]

formula[{1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

> ```
> (1 - 2) + (3 - 4)
> ```

---

Addressing your comment below the question, `Defer` (also `HoldForm`) *does* work, but the output formatting engine is changing the appearance of your result.  You can see this by using `InputForm`:

```
Defer[1 * 2 * 1 * 31] // InputForm
```

> ```
> Defer[1*2*1*31]
> ```

The hold functions, even `HoldComplete`, do not prevent the formatting engine form going to work:

```
HoldComplete[1 * 2 * 1 * 31]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You need to attack the problem at its source, by `Block`ing `Times` during Box creation:

```
SetAttributes[defer, HoldAll]

MakeBoxes[defer[args__], fmt_] :=
  Block[{Times},
    MakeBoxes[Defer[args], fmt]
  ]
```

You can now use `defer` as you would `Defer` but `Times` will not be formatted:

```
formula[{a_, b_, c_, d_}] := defer[a*b*c*d]

formula[{1, 2, 1, 31}]
```

> ```
> 1 * 2 * 1 * 31
> ```

Comment: +1 for simplicity of interpretation and solution.

Comment: Very very close, but per my note above, there are cases in which this collapses 1*x to x. Any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 10):

You are looking for partial evaluation. Perhaps, there is a shorter way, but here is one (rather subtle):

```
Clear[evalAtPattern]
evalAtPattern[expr_, p_] :=
   expr /. pt : p :> With[{pp = pt}, pp /; True];

Clear[formula];
formula[x_List] :=
  evalAtPattern[
    Defer[(x[[1]] - x[[2]]) + (x[[3]] - x[[4]])],
    HoldPattern[x[[_]]]];
```

Now,

```
formula[{1, 2, 3, 4}]

(* (1 - 2) + (3 - 4) *)
```

And the output code can be executed. The solution combined injecting evaluated pieces inside held expressions via Trott - Strzebonski technique, and the use of `Defer`.

Comment: It looks like Leonid had a different interpretation.

Comment: @R.M. His answer is simpler. It really depends on how general one wants to be. I tried to have code which can keep the original definition minimally modified.

Comment: +1 for complexity of interpretation and solution.  ps why not `expr /. pt : p :> RuleCondition[pt]` ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks :) No reason, really, just old habits.

Answer (score 4):

```
formula[{a_, b_, c_, d_}] := HoldForm[(a - b) + (c - d)]

formula[{1, 2, 3, 4}]
(1 - 2) + (3 - 4)
```

"...if I copy the output and paste it somewhere, I want it to be executable..."

You would need to release the hold.

```
ReleaseHold[(1 - 2) + (3 - 4)]
```

Comment: This works for me, as does the Defer[] solution above; I've credited Mr.Wizard for the answer only because he got in first.

Comment: I accepted, and then withdrew when I found a problem (discussed in an edit to my question, above). Mr. Wizard has since addressed this problem, so scores the point.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
formula[x_List] := 
    With[{a = x[[1]], b = x[[2]], c = x[[3]], d = x[[4]]}, Defer[(a - b)/(c - d)]]
```

?

Comment: @rm -rf Thanks!

Comment: This does not match the specification in the question as you cannot copy & paste the output as evaluable input; that is best done with `Defer`, introduced in version 6.

Comment: Thanks!@Mr.Wizard The function `Defer` is really amazing. It is like HoldForm with ReleaseHold command if copy & paste it.

Comment: I have modified it by replacing `HoldForm` into `Defer`.