# Why does TraditionalForm[Inactivate[x y]] show x * y ? instead of x y?

Tags: output-formatting

Given that both `x` and `y` are expressions, in my case `x` is `Transpose[A]` and `y` is `B`, I thought that the `TraditionalForm` for multiplication was juxtaposition with a space between.  Why is the `Output` for `TraditionalForm[Inactivate[x y]]` displayed with `*` visible?  I am working in *Mathematica* **V10**. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not clear to me if this is intended behaviour or not.  Instead of asking here, I'd write to Wolfram support.  They'll either tell you why, or will confirm it as a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider this:

```
Inactivate[3*5 - 2 - 3] // FullForm
```

> ```
> Inactive[Plus][Inactive[Times][3, 5], -2, -3]
> ```

RunnyKine is correct regarding the cause but he did not really explain the mechanism involved.  Formatting rules typically apply to (sub)expressions with certain heads.  This has nothing to do with evaluation per se, but rather the patterns in the transformation rules of [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MakeBoxes.html).

In this example the formatting rules for `Times` are still applied despite [`HoldComplete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldComplete.html):

```
HoldComplete[Times[x, y]] // TraditionalForm
```

> HoldComplete[*x* *y*]

Another example and further explanation can be seen in my answer to:

- [Returning an unevaluated expression with values substituted in](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7880/121)

Simply put `Inactive[Times]` does not match the patterns used by `MakeBoxes` for pretty formatting.  However we can easily add our own rules.  If you wish to have expressions produced by `Inactivate` formatted as the normal form of the expression (without evaluation) you may use:

```
MakeBoxes[p : Inactive[h_][args___], form_] := 
  MakeBoxes[Interpretation[HoldForm @ h[args], p], form]
```

Now the expression is formatted using the normal rules for `Times` and `Plus`:

[image]

Without the definition this is printed without the nice formatting:

[image]

Comment: This was very helpful! Especially the link. Many thanks.

Comment: @JohnMcGee You're welcome.  By the way I note that you have not [Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) any answers.  Please consider participating in this way.

Answer (score 8):

Because `Inactivate` acts on `Head`s of expressions, replaces them with `Inactive[h]` where `h` is the `Head` of the expression and prevents them from evaluating. And in your case the `Head` of `x y` is `Times`:

```
FullForm[x y]
```

> Times[x, y]

So

```
Inactivate[x y]
```

Gives:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Where the `Times` did not evaluate. Hence, the result you get when you apply `TraditionalForm`.

Answer (score 2):

Mr. Wizard's answer is excellent.  My main addition would be that the advantage of the method we chose is that the output is editable: you can copy it to another cell, add/remove/change terms, revaluate, and it all just works.  Using Interpertation as suggested would have preserved the meaning upon reevaluation but at the cost of destroying all editability. Certainly different tradeoffs are possibie, and the traditional form of Times in particular is a close call, but we decided that consistency with other operators was better than perfectly reproducing the TraditionalForm of Times.

Comment: Thanks for some inside information!