# How to write a TraditionalForm for non-commutatively multiplied objects

Tags: output-formatting, traditional-form

I would like to write a `TraditionalForm` output for a string of non-commutatively multiplied objects.

I don't really like the default output of the built-in symbol `NonCommutativeMultiply`, because it inserts $*\!*$ between each pair of symbols.

```
NonCommutativeMultiply[a, c + d, c] // TraditionalForm
```

> $a*\!*\,(c+d)*\!*\,c$

If I would like to format `OperatorProduct[a,(c+d),c] // TraditionalForm` like $a\,(c+d)\,c$, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) along with [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html)

First, need to [`Unprotect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unprotect.html) NonCommutativeMultiply:

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
Format[NonCommutativeMultiply[x__], TraditionalForm] := Inactive[Times][x]
```

This will look like:

```
NonCommutativeMultiply[a, c + d, c] // TraditionalForm
```

$a*(c+d)*c$

which is not quite right yet.  For the finishing touches we get [some help from Mr. Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56246/why-does-traditionalforminactivatex-y-show-x-y-instead-of-x-y/56272#56272)

```
MakeBoxes[p : Inactive[h_][args___], form_] := 
 MakeBoxes[Interpretation[HoldForm@h[args], p], form]
```

Now the result is

```
NonCommutativeMultiply[a, c + d, c] // TraditionalForm
```

$a(b+d)c$

as desired.  Beware of course that if you try to interpret this an input it will not be noncommutative.

Comment: Very nice.  I managed to consolidate your answer into a one-liner: `Format[NonCommutativeMultiply[x__], TraditionalForm] := 
 HoldForm@Times[x]`  (after unprotecting)

Comment: Of course, I need to quit forgetting about the usefulness of HoldForm.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) to do this (I also included a tooltip to be able to distinguish it from normal multiplication):

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
MakeBoxes[NonCommutativeMultiply[a__], TraditionalForm] ^:= TemplateBox[
    Thread @ Unevaluated @ Parenthesize[{a},TraditionalForm,Times,None],
    "NonCommutativeMultiply",
    DisplayFunction -> (RowBox[{SlotSequence[1]}]&),
    Tooltip -> "**"
]
Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
```

Using a [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) means the output is copy/pastable. For instance:

```
NonCommutativeMultiply[a, b + c, d] // TraditionalForm
```

> [image: a(b+c)d]

Copying the above output and evaluating:

[image]

> a ** (b + c) ** d

gives the usual [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm) output for [`NonCommutativeMultiply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply).