# How to change styling of HoldForm expressions?

Tags: output-formatting, hold

I lost some time trying to figure out why I got

```
f[]~MatchQ~f[]
```

> False

Copy pasting or using `// Hold // FullForm` showed what the problem is

```
\!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"f", "[", "]"}],
HoldForm]\)~MatchQ~f[]
```

The lefthand side was copy-pasted from somewhere (probably a message) where it was displayed in `HoldForm`.

I would like such expressions to look differently.

In version 11 we finally got different styling of Initialization cells (gray background), not just a tiny "I" in the cell brace. `Inactivated` expressions also display differently. But HoldForm are visually indistinguishable from regular input.

Can I do something to change the formatting of `HoldForm` expressions? Which `Format` rules or stylesheets do I have to change to get this?

Comment: Somewhat related: [(56715)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56715/121)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this now:

```
Unprotect@HoldForm;
Format[HoldForm[x_], 
   StandardForm] := {boxes = MakeBoxes@x, bg = LightBlue}~With~
   RawBoxes@
    InterpretationBox[
     TagBox[StyleBox[boxes, Background -> bg], "", 
      Selectable -> False], HoldForm[x]];
Protect@HoldForm;
```

The `TagBox` stops you from selecting anything inside the expression.

This makes the result clearer:

[image]

Another variant would be to just make `HoldForm` display directly like `Hold`, but the visual clutter might be unacceptable to you:

```
Format[HoldForm[x_], StandardForm] := 
  RawBoxes@TagBox[RowBox@{"HoldForm", "[", MakeBoxes@x, "]"}, "", 
    Selectable -> False];
```

(I left out the `InterpretationBox` here - TODO)

For reference, this is what HoldForm does by default:

```
Format[HoldForm[x_], StandardForm] := 
  RawBoxes@TagBox[MakeBoxes@x, HoldForm];
```

Answer (score 3):

Nice idea.  Your original construct did not play well with [`ReleaseHold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReleaseHold.html) though; here is one that should:

```
MakeBoxes[x_HoldForm, StandardForm] :=
  Block[{$holdstyle = True},
    Interpretation[
      Style[x, Background -> LightBlue, StripOnInput -> False, Selectable -> False],
      x
    ] // ToBoxes
  ] /; ! TrueQ[$holdstyle]
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed a problem with `ReleaseHold` in the current version.

Comment: @masterxilo So I see.  I guess then I'll emphasize the ability to use `Style` rather than `StyleBox` etc., making writing this just a little easier.

Comment: I did not think of catching nested `HoldForm`, I guess your version will perform better in such cases.